# Url redirection in yii before loading any action method?

Tags: php, yii

I have been suffering from redirection problem. I have developed a user module. Under this user module I have created a controller with a login action method. I want to make sure only authenticated users can access a module or static page in my app.

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        {
            $ab = Yii::app()->user->loginUrl;
            echo $ab;

            $controller->redirect($controller->createUrl(reset(Yii::app()->user->loginUrl)));

            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: i have set login `code`'components'=>array(
  'user'=>array(
   // enable cookie-based authentication
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login/login'),
  ),

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable 'Access Control Filter' on each controller/actions that you want to protect.

To enable access control filter, add this method to the controller:

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl',
        );
    }
}
```

And then, configure access control rules to make sure only NON-GUEST users have access to controller actions:

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('deny',
                'users'=>array('?'), //Deny all guest users
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Now, when a guest user tries to access MyController, they will automatically be redirected to your login page.

To finalize everything, you need to tell Yii where to find your login page.

You can set a custom login url in Yii configuration (main.php) file in the components section:

```
array(
    ...
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            'loginUrl'=>array('someModule/someController/someAction'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

By default, Yii have url set to `site/login`

For more information, see this Yii Authentication Guide:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth